# The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

Throwing

> "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)"

error in `WKNavigationDelegate` method `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error)`

each time when i try to load the html string.

Comment: @EDUsta Yes there might be possible of another request is made before the previous request is completed. what is the solution for that. ? Hw to cancel the previous request in WKWebView.

Comment: @EDUsta wanna to say this question already been asked. the link he given.

Comment: @MRizwan33 exactly, thanks. 

SriMa:  That would be another question, which I suggest you to open up. (here's a link that might be useful: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414981-stoploading)

Comment: @EDUsta I tried stopLoading() before loading another page. Still I getting the same error.